# Removing escape characters in json using Java

Tags: java, json

I am new in Java coding, I am trying to post a JSOn file, here is my JSON file object

```
{
  "report": "[{\"patientId\":\"abcd-efg\",\"campaignId\":\"2\",\"phoneCallsMade\":\"[]\",\"message\":\"[]\"}, {\"patientId\":\"abcd-efg\",\"campaignId\":\"2\",\"phoneCallsMade\":\"[]\",\"message\":\"[]\"}]"
}
```

I am trying to remove the backslash, I tried below methods :

```
myJsonString.replaceAll("\\","");
myJsonString=myJsonString.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

but after doing that the json format is not valid. Can someone help me please.

Comment: In that JSon file "report" is just a long String value. It is not a json object itself. (Its a String representation of a json object). To turn it into a valid JSon you at least need to remove the `"` from the start and end of your `"[{\"pa .... "}]"` object as well.

Comment: Ok let me try this change

Answer (score -1):

This is just a string not a json array.  And the reason of getting invalid json post removing slashes is due to in correct mapping of double quotes. Just remove double quotes from "[ & ]" from beginning and from end and perform the operation. Your problem will be resolved.
{
"report": [{
"patientId": "abcd-efg",
"campaignId": "2",
"phoneCallsMade": "[]",
"message": "[]"
}, {
"patientId": "abcd-efg",
"campaignId": "2",
"phoneCallsMade": "[]",
"message": "[]"
}]
}

This will be the output.